# How to share variables between two threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am a beginner learning Java. Now I have a question, could someone help me solve it?  :)

I have a class named Server which maintains a hashmap variable, and I it has two methods named send() and receive(). I want the two methods to run concurrently.
The send() method will use the hashmap variable and the receive() method will change the hashmap variable.

Please help work it out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());`

Edit 1: code template

```
public class Server
{
    private static Map<String,String> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, String>());

    public void send()
    {
        //
        // Do some operation using map variable
    }

    public void receive()
    {
        // change the map variable as you want
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: could u give me a code template for my question? I really don't know how to write the code. Thx

Comment: thanks for your codes! And how can I let the two methods run at the same time?

Comment: You run your program in multithreaded environment??

Comment: yes, I am using this way to solve it: I create two thread classes and put send and receive methods in each of the run() method of the two thread classes. The execute the thread.start() method. is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Define the HashMap in the main thread that spawns the send and receive threads. Make sure you use a SynchronizedMap so that you don't run into race condition.

Comment: could u give me a code template for my question? I really don't know how to write the code. Thx

Comment: this question has been asked before. You can checkout the questions listed at the top. If you're still having trouble, we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Items are shared by default. What you'll need is some form of lock or mutex to control sharing and prevent the two threads from trying to modify it at the same time.

Or, you can just use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: could u give me a code template for my question? I really don't know how to write the code. Thx

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions, simplest one is to use thread safe hashmap i.e. ConcurrentHashMap. You need not to worry about the synchronization issues as JVM will take care of it.
It will be good to go through the Javadoc for the same:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Other way is to synchronize the send() and receive()methods or the portion of the methods where you update the hashmap.

Comment: could u give me a code template for my question? I really don't know how to write the code. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use [COncurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

It allows concurrent modification of the Map from several threads without the need to block them.